# Illegal value at 'filematch': patternSet{ includes: [Index_*.xml] excludes: [] }

Tags: ant

I have to search a given string "OK" from a file Index_*.xml. This * is a random generated Id. This file is generated after every 15seconds

This is what I have done so far, but I am getting the exception " Illegal value at 'filematch': patternSet{ includes: [Index_*.xml] excludes: [] }"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="StringSearch" default="wait-for-some-time" basedir=".">
    <patternset id="filematch">
<include name="Index_*.xml"/>
</patternset>   
<target name="wait-for-some-time">
<waitfor maxwait="15" maxwaitunit="second" timeoutproperty="notfound">
    <resourcecontains refid="filematch" substring="OK" />
</waitfor>
<antcall target="success" />
</target>
<target name="success" depends="fail" unless="notfound">
    <echo message="String OK found" />
</target>
<target name="fail" if="notfound">
    <echo message="String not found" />
</target>
</project>
```

Any suggestion of what is wrong here or may be another approach if this is not feasible.
Thanks

New code:
Using this

```
<path id="pathtoIndexfile">
    <fileset dir="${destination.dir}">
         <include name="Index_*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

<target name="wait-for-some-time">          
    <echo>${destination.dir}</echo>
    <waitfor maxwait="1" maxwaitunit="minute" timeoutproperty="notfound">
    <resourcecontains refid="pathtoIndexfile" substring="OK" />     
    </waitfor>
    <antcall target="success" />            
</target>
```

1) The exception is "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path cannot be cast to org.apache.tools.ant.types.Resource".
2) With fileSet the exception is "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet cannot be cast to org.apache.tools.ant.types.Resource"

Am I missing some Jars?

Comment: I deleted my initial answer that suggested to use `fileset`, this is wrong as `resourcecontains` needs a single resource.  My later answer used `restrict` and `resourcecount` but won't work unless you know the file name - this is because you can't get `fileset`'s pattern matching without its built-in caching.  So you won't see any file added to the directory after the initial scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the solution by two steps which are as follows:

1. Step 1: Copying the index_*.xml file to output.xml file
2. Step 2: Search OK in the output.xml file

My improvised code which does the search of a string "OK" is

```
<target name="StringSearch">
    <sleep seconds="10"/>
    <copy tofile="${destination.dir}/output.xml">
            <fileset dir="${destination.dir}">
                <include name="Index_*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    <sleep seconds="10"/>
    <echo>destination.dir is: ${destination.dir}</echo>
    <loadfile property="OK.exists" srcfile="${destination.dir}/output.xml">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="OK"/>
            </linecontainsregexp>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <echo>OK exists: ${OK.exists}</echo>
</target>
```